# Navigating the tree in projection query in breezejs

Tags: javascript, breeze

In EntityFramework I am able to do this kind of projected query:

```
return currentQuery.Select(
     x => new PickSearchableItem()
              {
                  Text = x.FullName,
                  ID = x.ID,
                  PersonAddress = x.PersonAddresses
                                   .FirstOrDefault( y => y.IsPrimary == true)
                                   .Address1,
               });
```

Is there any way to replicate this kind of behavior client-side with breeze? The trouble we're having is navigating the tree in the select of the projection.

Answer (score 0):

Breeze client side projections are currently limited to fairly simple property projections with any of the standard odata functions optionally applied.  Your query is a bit more complicated.

However, you can define much of this projection on the server and expose the projected IQueryable as an IQueryable of Object and have the client filter against this.

Does this make sense?

Comment: That is what we resorted to. We just hoping to so most of our querying client side and just exposing specific each table as a resource on the server. It's not too big of a deal to do it server side though